# Django rest frame getting values from all tables where the PK is referenced as FK

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

With my parent model - `StudioProfile`, other models have a foreign key relationship to `StudioProfile`. How can I get all related table data when an API request is made to my `StudioProfile` serializer. Below are my models, views and serializers,

```
class StudioProfile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
    address_1 = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    address_2 = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

class StudioServices(models.Model):

    studio_profile = models.ForeignKey(StudioProfile, related_name = "services")
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

class StudioPicture(models.Model):

    studio_profile  = models.ForeignKey(StudioProfile, related_name = "pic_of_studio")
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'img_gallery', null = True, blank = True)
```

Serializers.py

```
class StudioServicesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = StudioServices
        fields = ('studio_profile',   'service_name')

class StudioPicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = StudioPicture
         fields = ('picture') 

class StudioProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    services = StudioServicesSerializer(source = "StudioServices")
    pic_of_studio = StudioPicSerializer(source = "StudioPicture")
    class Meta:
        model = StudioProfile
        fields = ( 'address_1', 'address_2','services','pic_of_studio' )
```

views.py

```
class StudioProfile(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (ReadWithoutAuthentication,)
    serializer_class = StudioProfileSerializer
    queryset = StudioProfile.objects.select_related().filter(id = 1)
```

Am not able to get the data. What am I doing wrong here? When I do a request to `StudioProfile` class how can I get all the related entries.

Traceback:

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `service_name` on serializer `StudioProfileSerializer`.
>   The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `StudioProfile` instance.
>   Original exception text was: 'StudioProfile' object has no attribute 'StudioServices'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you might need to include many=true and change the source to the be related_name in the StudioProfileSerializer:

```
class StudioProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    services = StudioServicesSerializer(many = true, source = "services")
    pic_of_studio = StudioPicSerializer(many = true, source = "pic_of_studio")
    class Meta:
        model = StudioProfile
        fields = ( 'address_1', 'address_2','services','pic_of_studio' )
```